# Unable to Populate data in sanity.io

Tags: reactjs, sanity

I am using sanity.io for backend purpose for creating a social media app, but the problem is, even after configuring the new google oauth process and setting up sanity correctly the data is not getting populated in the backend of sanity.io

I am using

```
client.createIfNotExists(doc).then((response) => {

                console.log("User Created: ", response);
                navigate("/", {replace: true});
});
```

to connect with the backend, the response generated in the console is as follows:
Check this image --> (https://i.stack.imgur.com/htOnk.png)

My client.js file looks like this:

```
import { createClient } from '@sanity/client';
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';

export const client = createClient({

    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
    dataset: 'production',
    useCdn: true,               // set to `false` to bypass the edge cache
    apiVersion: '2023-05-15',   // use current date (YYYY-MM-DD) to target the latest API version
    token: process.env.REACT_APP_SANITY_TOKEN,
    ignoreBrowserTokenWarning: true
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);
export const urlFor = (source) => builder.image(source);
```